# Get a comma separated field from different table

Tags: mysql

Having a student and subject table. Is it possible that by only using MySQL I can combine the values in one field as comma separated.

Student table

```
sid | subject_id
 1  |   1,2
 2  |   1
 3  |   2
 4  |   1,2,3
```

Subject Table

```
   subject_id | subject_name
        1     |   Maths
        2     |   Sci
        3     |   Eng
        4     |   Eco
```

Required Result

```
        sid   | subject_name
        1     |   Maths,Sci
        2     |   Maths
        3     |   Sci
        4     |   Maths,Sci,Eng
```

Code I tried

```
SELECT
  student_table.sid,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    subject_table.subject_name
  )
FROM
  student_table
LEFT JOIN
  subject_table ON student_table.subject_id = subject_table.subject_id
```

Comment: don't put multiple values into a column.  have sid multiple times for each subject in your student table. so a `(1,1), (1,2)...` should exist.

Comment: lets say i dont have control on database i just read the data

Comment: the use of comma separated  values  is based on bad db design concept .. you should avoid  ..

Comment: lets say you learn from your mistakes and can correct it.

Comment: dear @danblack i am not in that level were i can ask the company to change the structure of db right now.

Comment: You should take a note of their expertise and find a different employer. If they aren't one to recognize faults or improve basic practices from whatever level they come from they are unworthy of you time. If you aren't willing to raise it you aren't doing your job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SUBSTRING_INDEX in the select and also use the CHAR_LENGTH on your join condition. [Sample code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c255/1)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT student.id, GROUP_CONCAT(subject.subject_name)
FROM student
LEFT JOIN subject ON FIND_IN_SET(subject.subject_id, student.subject_id)
GROUP BY student.id
```

All you need to have is the function "FIND_IN_SET", for joining the tables.